# Retorno do banco de dados em função assíncrona com await

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-update

Tenho uma função assíncrona que preciso usar um `await` no retorno do banco de dados para usar esse dado posteriormente quando for fazer a próxima inserção usando o `LAST_USER_ID()` do MYSQL, porém, utizlizando o `await` ele para a execução ali e aparentemente fica esperando mais resultados do que já tem e não prossegue mais.

Quando não uso `await` e coloco um `setInterval()` pra chamar uma função e fazer a próxima inserção tudo acontece como esperado, caso contrario ele tenta executar antes de ter o resultado da anterior.

Aparentemente o `await` espera mais resultados do que estou esperando e nunca pula para a próxima parte.

Alguém poderia me ajudar encontrar onde estou errando?

Segue abaixo o código:

```
function sqlquery(str, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query(str, params, (err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        })
    })
}
```

```
async function tudo() {
    console.log(`\n> Registrando 1...\n`)
    await sqlquery("INSERT INTO `log` (`data`, `horainicio`) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME());", function lastId(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        idRegistro = result.insertId
        console.log(`\n> Registrado 1.\n`);
    });

    console.log("\n> Registrando 2...\n");
    await sqlquery(`UPDATE log SET horafim = CURRENT_TIME() WHERE idlog = ${idRegistro}`)
    console.log("\n> Registrado 2.\n");
}
tudo();
```

resultado

```
node mysql.js

> Registrando 1...


> Registrado 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando uma função de `callback` ao mesmo tempo que usa `await`. Não há necessidade de fazer isto, já que você converteu `con.query` usando *Promise* na função `sqlquery`, sem falar que esta não usa `callback`, como você mesmo especificou nos parâmetros `(str, params)`.

Com a função `sqlquery`, ela já retorna o valor de `idRegistro` simplismente fazendo um `let idRegistro = await sqlquery(...);`.

Eu fiz um *mock* do seu código e veja como ele se comporta:

```js
const con = { // esse mock seria semelhante a sua "con"
  query: (str, params, callback) => {
    let err, result = null;
    return callback(err, result);
  }
};

function sqlquery(str, params) { // voce converteu aqui e pode usar await no lugar de callback
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(str, params, (err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve({ insertedId: 1 }); // retorna 1 só para exemplificar
    });
  });
}

async function tudo() {
  console.log(`\n> Registrando 1...\n`);

// await sqlquery("INSERT INTO `log` (`data`, `horainicio`) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME());", function lastId(err, result) {
//   if (err) throw err;
//   idRegistro = result.insertId
//   console.log(`\n> Registrado 1.\n`);
// });

  // use await normalmente, ela vai lhe retornar o id.
  let idRegistro = await sqlquery("INSERT INTO `log` (`data`, `horainicio`) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME());");
  console.log(`\n> Registrado 1.\n`);
  console.log(idRegistro); // agora que o await de cima acabou, vai aparecer 1

  console.log("\n> Registrando 2...\n");
  await sqlquery(`UPDATE log SET horafim = CURRENT_TIME() WHERE idlog = ${idRegistro}`); // faz a query com o idRegistro igual a 1 
  console.log("\n> Registrado 2.\n");
}

tudo();
```

Agora para tratar qualquer erro que será lançado por `if (err) reject(err);`, basta envolver seu código em `try/catch` e trata os erros no bloco `catch`.

```
const con = {
  query: (str, params, callback) => {
    let err, result = null;
    return callback(err, result);
  }
};

function sqlquery(str, params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(str, params, (err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve({ insertedId: 1 });
    });
  });
}

async function tudo() {
  try {
    console.log(`\n> Registrando 1...\n`);

    // await sqlquery("INSERT INTO `log` (`data`, `horainicio`) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME());", function lastId(err, result) {
    //   if (err) throw err;
    //   idRegistro = result.insertId
    //   console.log(`\n> Registrado 1.\n`);
    // });

    let idRegistro = await sqlquery("INSERT INTO `log` (`data`, `horainicio`) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME());");

    console.log(idRegistro);

    console.log("\n> Registrando 2...\n");
    await sqlquery(`UPDATE log SET horafim = CURRENT_TIME() WHERE idlog = ${idRegistro}`);
    console.log("\n> Registrado 2.\n");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // trata os erros aqui
  }
}

tudo();
```